# dynamic docker-compose config from env

Tags: docker, docker-compose, config

Is there a tool to dynamically set `services`, `external_links`, etc. for container orchestration, depending on an environment variable?

Tool should have convenient syntax (Python/js/bash - any clearly readable), and support conditions (if).

Now I have 3 files like `docker-compose.local.yml`, and edit them all.

```
cp docker-compose.local.yml docker-compose.yml;
docker-compose up;
```

I wan't one config file

```
ENV=local;
docker-compose up; # or "node start-compose.js"
```

I know that docker-compose supports environment variables like

```
volumes:
  - ${ENV}-filename:/.../filename
```

But I need more.

Comment: Docker compose supports passing multiple files as arguments. It then "merges" them into one config file and so it allows you to customize specific fields in specific files. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.env` files to store all your compose configuration.

Just as you do `cp docker-compose.local.yml docker-compose.yml;` You do `cp local.env .env;` `docker-compose up` will automatically pick up the `.env` file.

Taken from the docs [Environment Variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)

Comment: I tried it and if I put this line into .env file: `HOST_USER=${whoami}` then I put this line into my any.dockerfile: `RUN echo ${HOST_USER}` it contains empty string.