# How to use dynamic generated values in docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Can I use dynamic generated values in `docker-compose.yml` file like in the code below?

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./.docker-config/dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
      args:
        - HOST_UID=${id -u}
        - HOST_GID=${id -g}
        - HOST_USER=${whoami}
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html:delegated
```

...and in the `php.dockerfile`:

```
ARG HOST_UID
ARG HOST_USER

RUN useradd $HOST_USER -u $HOST_UID
```

It says:

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "build" option in service "php": "HOST_UID=${id -u}"
```

I think now the parameter passed into container contains this string: `${id -u}` and not the value of the expression.

Can I somehow pass in the result of the expression?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377853/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-docker-compose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62121588/how-to-evaluate-a-dynamic-variable-in-a-docker-compose-yml-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57880893/how-can-i-set-runtime-variable-for-docker-compose-environment-variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234896/dynamic-docker-compose-config-from-env

Comment: What you're trying to do can't be done. You ought to set the environment variables beforehand (either .env file or in the shell) and set the variable substitution to the name of the environment variables you've chosen, as KamilCuk's comment points out

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, I googled it before ask. Your linked questions are all operates insanely complex command line commands or operates with environment variables from command line. Environment variables are an unneccessary complexity level for easy-to-use docker configuration. If it's possible I want to keep as simple as possible the developers job when they start using containers. Nor 1000 chars lenght commands, nor bash env variable are enough simple for my needs.

Comment: I do not understand. Your question is `Can I somehow pass in the result of the expression?` the answer is "Yes, use env variables". This is how it is. If you want to enable shell execution as part of variable expansion in docker-compose, patch docker with that functionality. You can use a preprocessor, like m4, to execute a command, which boils down to docker-compose.yml generation.

Comment: I picked one of @KamilCuk's suggestions that most closely matches this question, and another that more directly matches the "build the host uid into the image" use case.  Note that recompiling the image for every possible host user isn't generally a good practice; if my host uid is 501, why can't I use your image?

Comment: @DavidMaze that is exactly why I  want to pass in the current user's data into the container

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variables as environment variables on your `docker-compose build` command, like this

```
HOST_UID=$(id -u) HOST_GID=$(id -g) HOST_USER=$(whoami) docker-compose build
```

Then you need to change your docker-compose file to get the values from the environment variables, like this

```
args:
  - HOST_UID=${HOST_UID}
  - HOST_GID=${HOST_GID}
  - HOST_USER=${HOST_USER}
```

It's not as user-friendly as having the commands in the docker-compose file, of course.

Here's how I tested it:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - HOST_UID
        - HOST_GID
        - HOST_USER
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian
ARG HOST_UID
ARG HOST_GID
ARG HOST_USER
RUN echo ${HOST_UID}
RUN echo ${HOST_GID}
RUN echo ${HOST_USER}
```

Build command:

```
HOST_UID=$(id -u) HOST_GID=$(id -g) HOST_USER=$(whoami) docker-compose build --no-cache
```

Comment: sure, I know this works, but I want to avoid using more and more command line parameters. I'm looking for soultion to keep my command as simple as possible, like this `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: I know. But that's not possible, I think.

Comment: Now I tried to put this into the .nev file: `HOST_USER="djw"` and in the dockerfile `RUN echo "host user is ${HOST_USER}"` the result of this echo is this: `host user is ` and the variable contains still empty string

Comment: The .env file only applies to the docker-compose file. Not to Dockerfiles built with it. So you need to pass it on from the docker-compose file to the Dockerfile using `args`.

Comment: I pass it, but nothing

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how I tested it

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution to keep my command line command as simple as possible. This suggestion is working, but it's a brainmelting way... :) Now I try to use a `docker.env` file to keep there my variables, but still not working.

Comment: Environment variables are only available at run-time, so you can't use them at build time

Comment: So there isn't any way to store my variables in `.env` file or read it from a command at running `docker-compose up -d` ?